# execCommand не работает

Tags: javascript

Подскажите по этой функции. Где её вызывать?

Суть проблемы: есть поле textarea, вверху ссылки. При клике на ссылку должен форматироваться текст, но этого не происходит. Вот код:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
    mainDiv.id = 'mainDiv';
    document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
    var buttonControl = {
        'paragraf': '<a href = "#paragraf" id="paragraf" class="buttonControl">p</a>',
        'bold': '<a href = "#bold" id="bold" class="buttonControl">b</a>',
        'italic': '<a href = "#italic" id="italic" class="buttonControl">i</a>'
    };
    for (var property in buttonControl) {
        mainDiv.innerHTML += buttonControl[property];
    }
    var mainArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    mainArea.id = 'mainArea';
    mainDiv.innerHTML += '<br />';
    mainDiv.appendChild(mainArea);
    document.getElementById('bold').onclick = function (element) {
        mainArea.focus();
        window.document.execCommand('bold', null, '');
        element.preventDefault();
    };
};
```

Comment: Не работает тэг с Кодом, извините

Comment: @systemiv Между предыдущим текстом и блоком с кодом должна быть пустая строка, тогда он отформатируется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, для работы `execCommand()` необходимо включить `designMode` или `contentEditable` - посмотрите, например, в [доках Мозиллы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla). Во-вторых, вы не можете таким образом форматировать текст в `textarea` - этот элемент всегда хранит только текст. Однако вы можете форматировать текст, например, в диве (перед щелчком по ссылке выделите текст в `editDiv`):

```
...
for (var property in buttonControl) {
    mainDiv.innerHTML += buttonControl[property];
}

var editDiv = document.createElement('div');
editDiv.id = 'editDiv';
editDiv.innerHTML = "123123";
document.body.appendChild(editDiv);

document.getElementById('bold').onclick = function (event) {
    editDiv.contentEditable = true;
    window.document.execCommand('bold', false, '');
    editDiv.contentEditable = false;
    event.preventDefault();
};
```